# White frames appear after rendering na animation

Tags: rendering, animation

I have got a problem with rendering an animation (eevee). In my viewport everything works fine and the animation looks cool, but when I render it (I have tried to render as png and also as ffmpeg video) everything turns into just white frames. It is totally weird, because during rendering correct frames are appearing, but each frame turns white at the finish of rendering.
Do you know what's the reason? :)
[image]

That's how rendered frame looks

[image]

And that's my viewport

Comment: Ussually in outliner is something hidden from viewport but still enabled for render. Or ... Saved image is white or render in blender? In first case it can be something in Compositor. In the second you could accidentaly use short key to display Alpha channel in render window only? Better to post a simplified blend where issue still persist.

Comment: You're right, I accidentally disconected render layers node with composite. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I fixed it. The reason is quite silly - my render layers node wasn't connected to composite... :) 
So the solution is to check nodes in a compositor and connect everything what is important.